# Why isn't there any path from $A$ to $B$ when question $B$ is closed as a duplicate of question $A$?

Tags: support, close-reasons, linked-questions, duplicates

Let $A,B$ two questions and suppose $B$ is a duplicate of $A$. Then (usually) $B$ is closed and a link to question $A$ appears in $B$. However, it may happens that $B$ already got a useful answer which is also different (or better explained) from the answers proposed in $A$ (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066144/improper-integral-int-1-infty-frac-mathrm-dxxx1x2-cdotsxn) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066213/if-tk-id-for-k-ge-1-then-t-is-diagonalizable)). A copy-past of the answers proposed in $B$ in the answers of $A$ is clearly not always possible since the notations introduced by the OPs may be different.

**My question:** Why isn't there any path from $A$ to $B$ when question $B$ is closed as a duplicate of question $A$?

This would make sense to me because then the OP of $B$ would have access to ALL the answers to his question. For example, if $A,B,C$ are questions such that $B$ and $C$ are duplicates of $A$ and there is in $C$ an answer that would help the OP of $B$ more than the answers proposed in $A$.

Comment: I guess It is shown in linked section in sidebar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MetaSE](http://Meta.StackExchange.com) must have a thread related to this, but I'm unable to find it.

*I'm extending [my comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18723/why-isnt-there-any-path-from-a-to-b-when-question-b-is-closed-as-a-duplic#comment67345_18723) as an answer*.

As soon as a link<sup>[1]</sup> to question, answers or comment from thread $A$ is posted on  question, answers or comments of thread $B$, a link to linked thread will show up in 'Linked section' on sidebar. This link will be shown as long as the posted link is not removed.

---

<sup>[1]</sup>Note:
Not necessarily a visible link. 
For eg.`[](http://example.com)` Which is rendered as follow (without highlighting):

> 

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understood your answer (but I found your comment very helpful). Could you please rephrase it in a simpler english?

Comment: @Surb See [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/59DXC.png)

Comment: Thank you (I understood the sidebar thing, but your third sentence was hard to understand for me)

Comment: @Surb You understood it or not? (English is not my first language)

Comment: Now, yes I do (and thus accepted your answer :)

Comment: @Surb Glad it helped!